# Selecting from a column in a joined table in Views

Tags: 7, views

I've got two tables: {students} and {student_names}. Students is the base table, with a primary key of {students}.sid. Student names is the joined table, and has a key of {student_names}.sid.

I've defined my join in hook_views_data:

```
$data['students']['table']['join']['student_names'] = [
  'left_field' => 'sid',
  'field' => 'sid',
];
```

I want to select the given name of the student from the joined table. I've defined the field as follows (again in hook_views_data()):

```
$data['students']['given_name'] = [
  'title' => t('Given name'),
  'help' => t('The given (first) name of the student'),
  'field' => [
    'handler' => 'views_handler_field',
 　　'click sortable' => TRUE,
  ],
  'sort' => [
    'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
  ],
  'filter' => [
    'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_string',
  ],
  'relationship' => [
    'base' => 'student_names',
    'field' => 'sid',
    'handler' => 'views_handler_relationship',
  ],
];
```

I'm getting this error:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'students.given_name' in 'field list'

How can I tell views that the column is in the {student_names} table and not the {students} table?

Comment: You might need to try something like `$data['students']['sid']` instead of `$data['students']['given_name']` and then add relationship to `student_names` table, and then get the given name. Like we get the Author names for Content.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my own issue.

I needed to expose the joined table to views as well. So on top of setting up $data['students'], I also needed to set up $data['student_names'], with a join back to the original table. Here is my hook_views_data() in its entirity:

```
$data['student_names']['table'] = [
  'group' => t('Student'),
  'base' => [
    'field' => 'sid',
    'title' => t('Student'),
  ],
  'join' => [
    'students' => [
      'left_field' => 'sid',
      'field' => 'sid',
      'type' => 'inner',
    ],
  ],
];

$data['student_names']['given_name'] = [
  'title' => t('Given name'),
  'help' => t('The given (first) name of the student'),
  'field' => [
    'handler' => 'views_handler_field',
    'click sortable' => TRUE,
  ],
];

return $data;
```